# Latexproblem: font installed but cannot be mapped

Tags: fonts, errors

When I am compiling some latex, I get the following error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode cx --bdpi 300 --mag 1+84/300 --dpi 384 zptmcm7y
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for zptmcm7y.
mktexpk: perhaps zptmcm7y is missing from the map file.
```

which is strange, since I can find the zptmcm7y font with find:

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/zptmcm7y.tfm
```

If you need more information to help me, dont hesitate to ask!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.  It would most helpful if you provided (a) a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and (b) infomation about which system and tex engine you are using

Comment: Execute `updmap`.